# Structuring a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

I have set up a database with the following column headings, ID, POI, filename. 
I believe that I must set a Primary Key. At the moment that is ID. However, a customer may decide to change the order of their database, for example move ID 20 to number 2. But because it is a primary key, it cannot be duplicated. 
I tried to add in an extra column, I made that auto increment, and then make the ID column the primary key, however, i am being told that the auto increment column should also be the primary key.
Therefore, how can you set up a database that will allow the rows to be moved around?

Comment: Have another column called customer_order (or some similar name) and display your data ordered by that order column. Also change the order column's order when a customer changes the order. Do not play with primary keys. Its not supposed to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *ID* shouldn't change.  Ever.  It *identifies* the data.

Keep the auto-increment ID as the primary key and use it to identify the records.

It sounds like the customer is asking for a manual ordering/sorting value.  That's a separate concept than an identifier and should be a separate column.  Something like `SortOrder` perhaps.  A sort order doesn't *need* to be unique, and can really be any integer value.  So simply let it be exactly that... an integer column.

For use cases and business operations where the manually-specified sort order is applicable, `ORDER BY` that column.